# pgAdmin4: Save results to file - file doesn't show

Tags: windows, postgresql, export-to-csv

I am trying to save a CSV file of my SQL query in PgAdmin 4 to my local files (I am a beginner so please excuse me if the terminology is not correct). I clicked the "save result to files" button and selected the folder where I want it to be saved. When I look into this folder, there is nothing there. However, if I look into my "last used files" in my Windows explorer (sorry, I am translating this from German), there are the files, I just can't open them. When I clicked on them Excel opens and says it couldn't find it.

I also tried to save the files by writing a command under the query, didn't work either.

Comment: It is working if I save the file to a USB stick. When I save it to my desktop it supposedly doesn't work because my desktop is connected to One-Drive. How do I "let Onedrive speak with Postgres" so that I can just save the files on my computer and not on USB?

Comment: 'if I look into my "last used files" in my Windows explorer'   Is that the 'Recent Files' from 'File Explorer'?  Maybe you could change your settings to english temporarily so we know what it is you are seeing (or maybe post a screen shot of it).

Comment: What version of Windows?  (And what version of PgAmin4, thought that less likely to be relevant).